# Any free WiFi facility in Germany (Munich and Frankfurt Central Stations) or any closed place nearby?

Tags: germany, internet, wifi, munich, frankfurt

A friend of mine is travelling to Germany next week and looking for internet facility there. Is there any free WiFi access in Germany mainly in Frankfurt Hauptbahnhof and Munich (München Hauptbahnhof)?

He is particularly looking for free internet access close to Frankfurt and Munich train stations. Also any nearby places like supermarkets, shopping malls or shops which offers free WiFi service would also be considered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes.** DB, the German railway company, offers Wifi hotspot service at selected important stations which allow free surfing for 30 minutes. According to [their page](http://www.bahnhof.de/bahnhof-de/bahnhofsinformationen/WLAN.html) (in German; cannot find an English version), over 125 stations (listed there) offer the facilities; among them Munich central and Donnersbergerbrücke, Frankfurt central and Hauptwache and both cities’ airport stations.

To connect, just connect to the network *Telekom*. Open your browser with a random URL. Click *Online gehen* to connect; as soon as you can see the timer running down, you’re good to go.

In my experience, while the Wifi isn’t the fastest it is certainly useable.

Answer (score 2):

Same as anywhere else in the world (at least where people can be made to pay the price of a medium lunch for an insane amount of sugar and caffeine): Starbucks.